# Can't center a ul inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my navigation links inside the `div` but no matter what I've tried it won't work. I've tried `margin-left:auto`, `margin-right:auto`, but nothing...

Here is the section of CSS code:

```
#nav {
    display:block;
    background-color:#505050;
    height:17.5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px #CCCCCC inset;
    border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding:1.5%;
}
#nav li {
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
    display:inline;
    /*float:left;*/
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}
#nav li a {
    padding:0px 0px 20px 0px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

and here is my ul code:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Current Litters</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./bandi.html">Bandi</a></li>
            <li><a href="./studs.html">Studs Used</a></li>
            <li>Test Dog2</li>
            <li>Test Dog3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#form">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Here is the rest of my code
actually without it i noticed that my drop down menu under (gallery) doesn't display correctly, ...here is the rest of that css file...that shows what happens to the drop down...maybe you can tell me why the float screws it all up...

...and the text align did great....but only after removing the float...

```
#nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav li ul{
    padding:10px;
    font-size:medium;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:30px;
    background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.8);
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    border-radius:20px;
    border:1px solid;
    width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! We appreciate you showing your code and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `text-align: center` to the nav unordered list seems to work for me in chrome

```
#nav {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is actually quite simple, since your list items are `display:inline`. Add this style:

```
#nav {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fH6f5/

There are many other ways to do it, but this appears to be all you need. Just make sure not to `float` the `<li>`s (I see you have it commented out).

Comment: I gotta type faster, beaten to the post :)

Comment: @MarioVisic: Check this one out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116673/creating-an-faq-post-to-answer-the-css-question-how-do-i-center-something Actually, we might both be "wrong" on this one, OP says something about a `<div>` that's not in the code (and re-read the question title, "center a ul inside a div"). We may never know... ;)

Comment: nadmartigan is it bad to use float for navigation menus?

Comment: @Hira: No, not at all - it just doesn't work with `text-align:center`

Comment: actually without it i noticed that my drop down menu under (gallery) doesn't display correctly, ...here is the rest of that css file...that shows what happens to the drop down...maybe you can tell me why the float screws it all up...                                                           <code>  #nav li a:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
 }
#nav li ul{
 padding:10px;
 font-size:medium;
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:30px;
 background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.8);
 }
#nav li:hover ul {
 display:block;
 border-radius:20px;
 border:1px solid;
 width:150px;
 }
</code>

Comment: @Carine: If you have additional information, please add it to your post. Just click [edit]. Big chunks of code in comments doesn't fly here, and besides - I'm going on coffee break ;) Some one else can surely help you.

Answer (score 3):

To center a block element, you also need to explicitly set the width to some value, like this:

```
#nav {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few changes you're going to need to make to your code in order for it to display properly. Your list elements are currently `inline` elements. `inline` elements have a lot of restrictions, including not being able to explicitly set their width, height, and their top and bottom margin. Keep in mind that per the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3):

> Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements.

That being said, you can use `display: inline-block` with no problems for your current code. There is one very important thing to keep in mind about using `inline-block` elements: **whitespace**. Any space between `inline-block` elements in your code will be shown as a space on your browser. So, if you want the elements to be touching, their tags must be touching also:

```
<!-- Version A: This will produce a gap between the two elements -->
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>

<!-- Version B: This will not produce a gap between the two elements -->
<li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
</li><li>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
</li>
```

If you choose Version A from the code above, I'd recommend you `float` the elements rather than relying on `inline-block` for positioning. Centering a floated list is a bit more difficult than centering an `inline` list. Here's a way that I like to center floated elements:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav { overflow: hidden; }
nav ul {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0; }
nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    right: 50%;
    margin: 0 5px; }
nav ul li a { display: block; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/rsDbY/

You should post the design that you want for your dropdown menu, I don't really know what you want your final result to look like so I can't really help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a fixed width on your ul for `margin-right:auto` and `margin-left:auto`

Comment: i'm a bit confused about that...if you set a width, then doesn't that set the margins for it??...i mean, how would you lets say set a width of 50% and then margins of 5% each....how would that display....do you know what I mean....I'm so confused....any help on finding an excellent book or online course (for free) to learn all the nuances with css please let me know

Comment: Block elements take up as much width as possible by default. So let's say your `<ul>` is inside a wrapper that is 1000px wide.  By default the `<ul>` will also be 1000px wide(assuming padding and margin are both 0).  Now if we give the `<ul>` a width of 500px and set the left and right margins to auto then the browser automatically centers the div by making both left and right margins 250px.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `margin: 0 auto;` to `#nav` style? You also have to set the `ul` width to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more complicated then simply "text-align" as you have the text inside of a . You need to add "margin: 0px auto;" to your  element in your css file. This will then center the *divider* on the screen first, then center the next element within the divider and so on.