# Ul dropdown menus and shadow not aligning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with a menu I found at: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm

I modified it to be centered using the css edits in the 4th answer down on: [Can't center a ul inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762383/cant-center-a-ul-inside-a-div)

The problem is the drop down menus don't align themselves and I can't figure out how to make that happen.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ddsmoothmenu.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ddsmoothmenu.js">

/***********************************************
* Smooth Navigational Menu- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

ddsmoothmenu.init({
    mainmenuid: "smoothmenu1", //menu DIV id
    orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
    classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
    arrowswap: true,
    //customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
    contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
})



</script>
<title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="ddsmoothmenu" id="smoothmenu1">

<ul>
<li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/about.html">About Us</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="/history.html">History</a></li>
  <li><a href="/pc.html">Precepts and Credo</a></li>
  <li><a href="philan.html">Philanthropy</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a>Recruitment</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a>Rush Schedule</a></li>
  <li><a href="/rpfaqs.html">Rush/Pledging FAQs</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a>Calendar</a></li>
<li><a href="/forum/index.php">Forum</a></li>
</ul>
<br style="clear: left" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.ddsmoothmenu{
font: bold 12px Verdana;
background: #1c5a80; /*background of menu bar (default state)*/
width: 100%;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul{
position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

/*Top level list items*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li{
position: relative;
display: inline;
float: left;
text-align:center;
    right: 50%;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

/*Top level menu link items style*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li a{
display: block;
background: #1c5a80; /*background of menu items (default state)*/
padding: 8px 10px;
color: orange;
text-decoration: none;
}

* html .ddsmoothmenu ul li a{ /*IE6 hack to get sub menu links to behave correctly*/
display: inline-block;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a:link, .ddsmoothmenu ul li a:visited{
color: orange;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a.selected { /*CSS class that's dynamically added to the currently active menu items' LI A element*/
background: orange !important; 
color: #1c5a80;
}

.ddsmoothmenu ul li a:hover{
background: orange; /*background of menu items during onmouseover (hover state)*/
color: #1c5a80;
}

/* sub menus */
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul{
position: absolute;
left: -3000px;
display: none; /*collapse all sub menus to begin with*/
visibility: hidden;
}

/*Sub level menu list items (alters style from Top level List Items)*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{
display: inline;
float: none;
}

/*All subsequent sub menu levels vertical offset after 1st level sub menu */
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li ul{
top: 0;
}

/* Sub level menu links style */
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a{
font: normal 13px Verdana;
width: 160px; /*width of sub menus*/
padding: 5px;
margin: 0;
border-top-width: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

/* Holly Hack for IE \*/
* html .ddsmoothmenu{height: 1%;} /*Holly Hack for IE7 and below*/


/* ######### CSS classes applied to down and right arrow images  ######### */

.downarrowclass{
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
right: 7px;
}

.rightarrowclass{
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: 5px;
}

/* ######### CSS for shadow added to sub menus  ######### */

.ddshadow{ 
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
background-color: #ccc; /* generally should be just a little lighter than the box-shadow color for CSS3 capable browsers */
}

.toplevelshadow{
margin: 5px 0 0 5px; /* in NON CSS3 capable browsers gives the offset of the shadow */
opacity: 0.8; /* shadow opacity mostly for NON CSS3 capable browsers. Doesn't work in IE */
}

.ddcss3support .ddshadow.toplevelshadow {
margin: 0; /* in CSS3 capable browsers overrides offset from NON CSS3 capable browsers, allowing the box-shadow values in the next selector to govern that */
/* opacity: 1; */ /* optionally uncomment this to remove partial opacity for browsers supporting a box-shadow property which has its own slight gradient opacity */
}

.ddcss3support .ddshadow {
background-color: transparent;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaa; /* box-shadow color generally should be a little darker than that for the NON CSS3 capable browsers background-color */
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaa;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT:** The actual problem is that the contents of the sub-menu are getting displayed outside of the white (and shadowed) container. It needs to be displayed within the container.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) ur code

Comment: see your html code there is two <!DOCTYPE html> tag remove the second doctype.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it that the sub-menus are getting displayed outside of the white (shadowed) container? If yes, check if [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/YtWDL/) helps you. I just modified the CSS under `.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li`.

Comment: That's it exactly, I played around with it and it looks like putting display: inline;
float: none;
left: 0px;
in .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li
produces the desired result, even though it looks wierd on fiddle it it looks right on the actual page.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You got it.  Thanks again and Happy Thanksgiving. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the positioning of the sub-menu can be overcome by setting `left: 0px` as shown below:

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    display: list-item; /* or display: inline as you have mentioned */
    left: 0px; /* added this line to position */
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/YtWDL/)

Answer (score 1):

see your html code there are two `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag remove the second `doctype`.

and then try your code.

here i attach jsfiddle

http://fiddle.jshell.net/U34L5/

Comment: Is that fiddle a generic sample of ddsmoothmenu? It is using a vertical menu whereas the OP has a horizontal one. *EDIT:* Sorry, the fiddle has a horizontal example but it doesn't seem to be styled properly.

Comment: yes this fiddle is sample of ddsmoothmenu. and in fiddle there is two demo of horizontal and vertical. ya it's not styled proper @Harry